# How to filter Records based on the condition from Two Columns that are dependent

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a Table in the Database with below columns :

1. Month
2. Year
3. Name
4. xyz
5. abc

The table would have multiple Records but there is a unique constraint on the combination of Month, Year and Name.

The table would have data Like below :

```
  Month   Year    Name
1) 1       2016   test1
2) 2       2016   test2
3) 3       2016   test3
4) 1       2017   test4
5) 2       2017   test5
```

Now I want records that are Greater than or Equal to Month 3 and Greater than equal to Year 2016.
So the output Should be Like Below:

```
  Month    Year    Name
1) 3       2016   test3
2) 1       2017   test4
3) 2       2017   test5
```

How can this be accomplished. I am not getting any hint on how this can be done.I was adding a `where` clause with month>=3 and year>=2016 but it does not return any record and I think is correct as I am applying And condition on two expressions.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense! Greater than equal to doesn't include Months with values 1 and 2, should it?

Comment: With a where clause. You pretty much wrote the where clause in your question. Honestly this table is poorly designed. You should use dates instead of separate columns for month and year. You are struggling here because you chose the wrong datatype.

Comment: @Sean Lange This is how it is designed and Now I cannot change it. But if you could suggest me some solution on how this could be done. It would be Great.

Comment: Based on your question, your should not get the desired output. Lines 2 and 3 both contain `month < 3`. You want records that have a year greater than or equal to 2016 and month greater than or equal to 3.

Comment: @N00b Pr0grammer . This is what I need as a Output. The values that I get in output should be greater than the specified Month And Year.

Comment: @A2H This is what my question is about. How can I get the desired output.

Comment: `where year > 2016 or (year = 2016 and month>=3 )` this will produce the output as you have described in your table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To produce the result as you have described in your second table, I would write this query:

```
select [Month], [Year], [Name]
from Table -- your table name
where year > 2016 or ( year = 2016 and month >= 3) -- don't forget the parentheses.
```

What I can understand from your result table, the query described in words will be:

*Give me all the records where the year is greater than 2017 (in this case month doesn't matter, give me all the months) or if the year is 2016, give me all months greater than or equal to 3 (March included and onward). Don't give me any records where the year is smaller than 2016.*

If this is correct, then the query I posted above gives the right result.

Comment: I accepted your answer as Correct and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all records starting on or after `'2016-03-01'` then one way would be to build your `[year]` and `[month]` back into a `date` datatype.

```
select *
from t
where convert(date,convert(varchar(10),([year]*10000)+([month]*100)+1)) >= '20160301'
```

or in sql server 2012 +

```
select *
from t
where datefromparts([year],[month],1) >= '20160301'
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear. From the explanation you want "and" condition but in the output result it should be "or". For ex month >= 3 or year>=2016. This is your output saying.

Comment: I want the Output that I have mentioned. I was trying to apply and condition for that but it would not work. Also Or condition will definitely not work as It would return more rows as if any of the condition is satisfied it would display that in the output.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya's output is not saying `month >= 3 or year>=2016`. This will give all the records where the month is greater than 3 regardless of the year + all the records where the year is greater than 2016 regardless of the month.